# PHP str_replace slash and quote

Tags: php

I had my data called from db with words contained `'` such as `company's` and some words display like `company\\\\\'s`, despite I had a function to replaced all those special characters into normal, but wording  like `company\'s` is still around. Is there any proper way to replace all kind of special characters properly?

```
function chrEncode($data) {
    $data = str_replace('â€™', '&#39;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Ã©', 'é' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â€', '-' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('-œ', '&#34;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â€œ', '&#34;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Ãª', 'ê' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Ã¶', 'ö' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â€¦', '...' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('-¦', '...' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â€“', '–' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â€²s', '’' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('-²s', '’' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â€˜', '&#39;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('-˜', '&#39;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('-“', '-' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Ã¨', 'è' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('ï¼ˆ', '(' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('ï¼‰', ')' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â€¢', '&bull;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('-¢', '&bull;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Â§ï‚§', '&bull;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Â®', '&reg;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('â„¢', '&trade;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Ã±', 'ñ' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('Å‘s', 'ő' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace('\\\"', '&quot;' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace("\r", '<br>' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace("\\r", '<br>' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace("\n", '<br>' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace("\\n", '<br>' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace("\\\'", '&#39' ,$data);
    $data = str_replace("'", "&#39" ,$data);

    return $data;
}
```

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Take a look @ stripslashes: http://us1.php.net/stripslashes

Comment: Read this: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: Once you have escaped values in your database, you're basically screwed and you have to write a script to correct them; be careful though, because applying `stripslashes()` too many times is also not correct.

Comment: Why you don't use array like this 
`$data = str_replace(array(val, val, val), array(rep, rep, rep), $data)`
It's most comprehensive and just in one line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all special character by using preg_replace like this:

```
 preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);
```

or only for slashes:

```
$str = 'h///e/ll\\o\\//\\';
str_replace(array('\\', '/'), '', $str); // output hello
```

Another solution:- create a clean function

```
     function clean($string) {
        $string = str_replace('', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
     }
```

**Usage:-**

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
```

Will output: `abcdef-g`

Answer (score 3):

There is a inbuilt php function [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
echo stripslashes($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function when `insert` or `update`, and you will not have to replace special chars like `'`, `quot`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This are the special characters You need to escape them with extra backslash like this

```
str_replace("\\","", $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

[stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) is needed to get rid off the slashes...

```
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
```